# load from browser with htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, web, browser, html-agility-pack

At the moment, I'm trying to run example from the htmlaglitypack official site, but this code is broken: http://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser

I want to extract content after script completing. My code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "http://html-agility-pack/from-browser";
        var web2 = new HtmlWeb();
        var doc2 = web2.LoadFromBrowser(url, html =>
         {
             return !html.Contains("<div id=\"uiDynamicText\"></div>");
         });
        var t2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='uiDynamicText']");

        listBox1.Items.Add("Text 2: " + t2.InnerHtml + t2.OuterHtml);
    }
```

`t2` stay as null. What is the problem?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C# HTML Agility Pack Single Select Node returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17001884/c-sharp-html-agility-pack-single-select-node-returning-null)

Comment: I don't think so.

Comment: I only want to say that example from library official site is broken. If I will create condition for null result then it doesn't help. Or I'm not right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the HAP code also has wrong URL (missing ".net") so the code should read
string url = "https://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser";

Answer (score 2):

The [website](http://html-agility-pack.net/from-browser) says to use:

```
var t2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='uiDynamicText']").InnerText;
```

You are using different code:

```
var t2 = doc2.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(".//div[@id='uiDynamicText']");
```

Which explains why, with your code, `t2` is `null`.